# Execute shellscript from PHP (Localhost, Mac OSX)

Tags: php, macos, shell, localhost, mamp

I want to run a shell script from a php-based website on my localhost (using MAMP on Mac) but it does not work, unfortunately.

Heres's the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
open /Users/my_username/Desktop/aiSee.app
```

If I run it from the terminal, it works fine and opens the app. Using this code in my website, it does not work:

```
<?php 
    echo exec('script.sh');
?>
```

No errors or something are displayed, it just doesn't work.
The script is located at the same source as the .php file for the website.

Answer (score 0):

`open` in bash does not do what you think it does. You need `cat` instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /Users/my_username/Desktop/aiSee.app
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i´ve tried it - but it dosn´t work either. I´m not a terminal pro, but isn´t cat for concatenating files somehow ?

Comment: `cat` is for listing the file too. Does your shell file have '+x' permission? What will happen if you run `your_script.sh`?

Comment: It has +x permisson, done by:        chmod +x sript.sh. If I try to execute it from the terminal ist says /Users/.../aiSee.app is a directory. With "open" instead of "cat" it did actually open the aiSee Application. Could it be possible, that there is a problem between localhost (MAMP) and the native shell, running in the OS ?

Comment: "/Users/.../aiSee.app is a directory"? Ok what do you actually want to achieve in the first place?

Comment: I actually want to open aiSee. It´s an application that is able to draw graphs. The aim is to run it from a webapplication (localhost is ok for now) and i thought, the easiest way was to do it by a shellscript. In fact, if everything runs properly on a server, the script would be executed there.

Comment: I don't think you can simply do that. I.e. if you have some application running on localhost - you can't just push into web by having php script execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Has your issue been solved? 
If not, try `echo exec('sh script.sh');` or `echo exec('bash script.sh');`. 
This question may solve your problem: [how to run a .sh file from php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397672/how-to-run-a-sh-file-from-php)