# how to run an executable in html

Tags: html

Firstly, I am aware that this question has been asked before ([Is it possible to run an .exe or .bat file on 'onclick' in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980957/is-it-possible-to-run-an-exe-or-bat-file-on-onclick-in-html)) but I tried to do what was suggested and I could not make it work.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Launch Installer" onclick="window.open(file:///S:downloads/thing.sh)” />

</body>
</html>
```

This code is in a file called "test.html" in my downloads folder.
I ran it in command line with this command

```
open test.html
```

and that resulted in google chrome opening a blank page.

Also, I have an shell script in my downloads folder named "thing.sh" containing this code:

```
echo hello world
```

Thanks for the help.

**Using PHP** (I've tried fixing my file path and it still doesn't work)

I tried what was suggested in the link provided by james111 ([how to run a .sh file from php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397672/how-to-run-a-sh-file-from-php)) and this is my code:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec(‘Users/mathewlewis/downloads/thing.sh');
?>
```

I'm not sure how to run a php file from command line like I did with the html file (I have this code saved in a file called test.php) so I tried putting it in a file named test.html and that created a blank page in chrome like before.

Comment: First, your slashes are wrong. Second: it's not supposed to work. You will download the file rather than run it.

Comment: Third, your file address in .open() should be wrapped around quotes. Although it will download the file :)

Comment: For this you use applets, or uise object tag. However it's very often a security breac which is why it's not recommanded. Finally, you want to run a .sh file in client browser, how can it executes against a WIndows user ? It just can't. If you want to have your user download/or execute a setup file with the usual toolbox (download/execute). Just make a classic href pointing to that file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a file like this, plain and simple.

It'll just download the file, that's if your path was correct, which it isn't.

You may consider looking into a php alternative
[How to run abc.exe using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251634/how-to-run-abc-exe-using-php)

Run sh files [how to run a .sh file from php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397672/how-to-run-a-sh-file-from-php)

#### Edit:

You've tried to run a bash file using PHP, I'm assuming you're trying to run it from you `Downloads` folder?

Your path is incorrect, it should look something like this:

```
/Users/<user_name>/Downloads/thing.sh
```

But if you're running it from your server (in the folder of your php file), you'd reference the location based on the folder your php file is in.

Comment: Maybe not exactly like this, but there seems to be plenty of ways to launch an executable from the browser. A quick google search results in multiple questions and working answers around the topic in SO. It's not that plain and simple, especially if the file is already stored locally.

Comment: Yep, but the way the OP wants to do it you cannot. Which is why I've explicitly said that they cannot. @Roope

Comment: @james111 thanks for the link but I use a mac and it says it is only for windows. could you provide me with a mac method for running an executable in php or html. thanks

Comment: @mathew I've added a link to my answer

Comment: I just edited the question explaining how I tried to do what your link suggested.

Comment: @mathew - I've edited my answer...You must use the right file path.

Comment: I tried the new file path and that didn't work either. Also, like I mentioned in the edit, I don't know how to run a .php file so its in a .html file which I am running from command line using the command "open test.html" which is still creating a blank page. Just wondering if that is part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL Protocol to do the thing according to your requirement.
try this method, [Link to url Protocol sample](http://www.openwinforms.com/run_exe_from_javascript.html)