# Running shell scripts in PHP

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, server

I have an ubuntu server that I run and I was wondering if it is possible to start up game servers from my website.

As in like running the shell script in a screen and having the game server run continuously?

Comment: on the client side or the server side?

Comment: Well, yes it is possible, I think. Depends on your server-configration...

Comment: server side i think

Comment: making your game server a daemon service seems like a reasonable way to do it.  you'd have to configure your permissions in such a way that httpd can start/stop it, im a little fuzzy on that area though.

Comment: Would it also be possible to output the the progress of the server starting up like when in the putty or something?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is definitely possible.

You don't really need to know much PHP, in fact I would recommend something simple like a Perl or Bash script for the server side and just raw HTML (or PHP) to take care of the job.

Take a look at [how to run a .sh file from php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397672/how-to-run-a-sh-file-from-php)

You'll need to:

1. Create a server side script that runs whatever other script you run to start your game server
2. Make sure the script is accessible/responds to http requests

Depending on what you choose to use, it should be fairly simple to display the progress of the script and get it done. Keep in mind that there are many different ways to accomplish what you want to do so I'm not going into detail since I'm not even sure what kind of web server you're running.