# Run a .sh script in php

Tags: php, sh

I'm trying to run a .sh script in php.

Here's the sh code

```
 php fetchdrive.php
```

When I run the .sh script by double clicking, it works fine, and displays the variables I've returned (an array).
I'm using wampserver to run php. Multiple php files work properly, unfortunately this one can only be run command line, so I figure why not call the command via sh in my index.php file. When I try `<?php echo exec('sh C:/wamp64/www/run.sh'); ?>` in my index.php file, it doesn't work. I know this because at the bottom of the php file I'm trying to execute it has alert("Hello");

Infact I don't think it's running the command at all when I try to use echo exec.  All of this is because I'm trying to run a command "php fetchdrive.php" without having to manually type it in to terminal, since when I start running this server I won't have to re-run the command every time.

Any ideas?

Edit: Here's the script tag for the alert

```
<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Hello!"); </script>
```

It works on my other php files.

tl;dr I'm just trying to run a php terminal command within a website.

Comment: There is no alert function in PHP.

Comment: I have it in <script> tags

Comment: Why would you use `sh` to run a `bash` script from `php` that just runs another `php` program? Is your `run.sh` really in `/`?

Comment: Here's the full thing <?php echo exec('sh C:/wamp64/www/run.sh'); ?>

Comment: Yeah, whatever you're doing here smells bad. Quit now with dignity.

Comment: What approach do I use to calling a command then?

Comment: You could try shell_exec or passthru

Comment: you can see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397672/how-to-run-a-sh-file-from-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397672/how-to-run-a-sh-file-from-php)

Comment: okay sorry I Removed the b ash script and I'm just running it with sh right. I also changed to shell_exec and it's not doing anything. Is there a console log output I can use in sh to make sure it's executing the script in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did, so if it doesn't work for you then you may have some problem with WAMP or something. I might be wrong, but I don't think you're on a box that has real bash.

```
<?php
passthru(__DIR__ . '/lame.sh');
```

And the sh file (requires at least PHP v5.5 for the password_hash function):

```
#!/bin/bash
PASSWORD = 'kookoopapa1'
PHP=`which php`
PASSWORD=`$PHP -r "echo password_hash( '$PASSWORD', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 11] );"`
printf "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert(\"$PASSWORD\"); </script>\n"
```

Give it a shot. There's also a chance that your bash is not really at /bin/bash. In your terminal type "which bash" and see what it says. Modify your shebang as needed.